# Searching strings & match in a data frame in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I'd like to match the contents of a couple of columns of various data frames - the cells are regular expressions, and I'd like to use these over a loop to match so as to extract an associated value. For example:

```
head(DET_Data)
Gm.       Date  Tm H.A Opp Result  R RA Inn Record          Win        Loss   Save D.N  OU Total
2   2 2014-04-02 DET     KCR      W  2  1  10    2-0 Alburquerque     Collins          D 7.5
```

I'd like to match the batters in the Win column with the pitchers record, which is in a separate data frame:

```
          Pitcher Age  Tm Lg W L  W.L.  ERA  G GS GF CG SHO SV   IP  H R ER HR BB IBB SO HBP BK WP BF ERA.  FIP  WHIP  H9 HR9 BB9  SO9 SO.W
6 Al Alburquerque  28 DET AL 1 0 1.000 4.11 19  0  5  0   0  1 15.1 16 7  7  2  4   0 20   0  0  0 66  105 2.97 1.304 9.4 1.2 2.3 11.7 5.00
```

I'd like to be able to read the string contents, and use that to match with the pitcher name and so on. Is there a straight forward way of doing so ?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `grep`function, aren't you ?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: OK, thanks - didn't realise grep was in R! Will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grep function should help you :

```
x<-c("you","shall","not","pass")
grep("you",x)
[1] 1
grep("sha",x)
[1] 2
grep("314",x)
integer(0)
```

As you can see, the match has not to be the exact same to be found.